# In Stack Overflow how do I put the big green check to the answer which I like the most?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

In Stack Overflow how do I put the big green check to the answer which I like the most?

I see it on answers to other people's questions, but can't work out how to do it for my own.

Comment: There is a check box element right there. Just click it.

Comment: you can only do that if it's *your* question.

Answer (score 2):

That's called "accepting an answer" and is possible if you asked the question.

It looks so:[image: accept]

Answer (score 1):

You can only do this on answers to your own question and then, as a new user only after a time limit has passed (I believe it is 15 minutes currently).

You simply click on the checkmark that appears next to the answer.